# Python threading, non-blocking production

Tags: python, conditional-statements, producer-consumer, locks, thread-synchronization

The `ThreadedWorkerQueue.add_worker()` method blocks until a `Worker` has been consumed. Is there a nice design to allow adding new workers to the `ThreadedWorkerQueue` without blocking the thread calling `~.add_worker()`, but still working with conditions?

Here's a short SSCCE:

```
import time
import threading

class Worker(object):

    def work(self):
        pass

class TimeWorker(Worker):

    def __init__(self, seconds):
        super(TimeWorker, self).__init__()
        self.seconds = seconds

    def work(self):
        for i in xrange(self.seconds):
            print "Working ... (%d)" % i
            time.sleep(1)

class ThreadedWorkerQueue(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ThreadedWorkerQueue, self).__init__()
        self.condition = threading.Condition()
        self.workers = []
        self.running = False

    def add_worker(self, worker):
        with self.condition:
            self.workers.append(worker)
            self.condition.notify()

    def stop(self):
        with self.condition:
            self.running = False
            self.condition.notify()
        self.join()

    def consume(self):
        if self.workers:
            worker = self.workers.pop(0)
            worker.work()

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while True:
            with self.condition:
                if not self.running:
                    break

                self.condition.wait()
                self.consume()

def main():
    queue = ThreadedWorkerQueue()
    queue.start()

    queue.add_worker(TimeWorker(3))
    time.sleep(1)

    tstart = time.time()
    queue.add_worker(TimeWorker(2))
    print "Blocked", time.time() - tstart, "seconds until worker was added."

    queue.stop()

main()
```

#### Edit

Ok, so my original idea was that a Condition can be waked up when the Thread
can continue to consume Workers. This is the basic principle of the
Producer/Consumer design, to skip continuous polling and really only do the
work when there is work to do.

Just now, I had an idea using a lock that is acquired by default and is
released when new workers can be consumed. But I'm not sure if this is a
good method to do it. Can someone spot an issue (eg. potential deadlocks)?

The full code is on GitHub: https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/async/blob/73828ecaa2990a71b63caf93c32f9cce5ec11d27/async.py#L686-L750

```
class ThreadedWorkerQueue(WorkerQueue, threading.Thread):
    r""" This class implements the consumer design, introducing :class:`Worker`
    objects to start working as soon as there are new workers available. Every
    object adding Workers to this queue are the producers. """

    def __init__(self):
        WorkerQueue.__init__(self)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def __del__(self):
        if self.running:
            self.stop()
            warnings.warn("ThreadedWorkerQueue not stopped before its lost.")

    def notify(self):
        r""" Notify the ThreadedWorkerQueue that processing can be continued.
        It is usually not necessary to call this method manually. """

        try:
            self.lock.release()
        except (thread.error, RuntimeError):
            pass

    def stop(self, join=True, clear=False):
        r""" Interrupt the thread in its doing, pausing the threads actions
        until :meth:`start` is called again. All remaining workers are kept
        alive unless *clear* is specified True. """

        if clear: self.workers.clear()
        self.running = False
        self.notify()
        if join: self.join()

    def consume(self):
        r""" Just like :meth:`WorkerQueue.work_off`, but doesn't override
        the value of :prop:`running`. """

        while self.workers:
            worker = self.workers.popleft()
            self.current = worker
            worker.work()
        self.current = None

    # WorkerQueue

    def add_worker(self, worker):
        super(ThreadedWorkerQueue, self).add_worker(worker)
        self.notify()

    # threading.Thread

    def start(self):
        r""" Overrides :meth:`threading.Thread.start` to allow starting
        the ThreadedWorkerQueue multiple times. """

        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        return threading.Thread.start(self)

    def run(self):
        self.running = True
        while True:
            self.consume()
            if not self.running: break
            self.lock.acquire()
```

Comment: Do you use CPython for your multithreading component? If so, please take the following into account: CPython comes equipped with the global interpreter lock (GIL) which allows only one op-code of Python bytecode to execute at a time, regardless of how many threads may be running in a given Python process... This means that, all things being equal, a single process, even threaded, will run no faster on a 128 CPU machine than it will a single CPU machine. (taken from http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2005/10/does_python_have_a_concurrency.html)

Comment: @Jon It's for UI asynchrony, not trying to make things run faster

Answer (score 0):

> ... but still working with conditions?

You don't need conditions. Python already has a perfect mechanism exactly for this: [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue).  Change `ThreadedWorkerQueue.workers` from a list to a `Queue`, and you don't need to worry about conditions, locks, notifications, etc.  It will vastly simplify your code.

You need to replace:

- list of workers with a `Queue`
- append+notify with `Queue.put`
- wait+pop with `Queue.get`

and get rid of `with self.condition: ...`.

Also, it's not a good practice to call `self.join()` from within `stop()`. Leave it to the calling thread. In case you have several threads you need to stop, you'd want to first stop them all, and only then join them all.

Comment: Ok, well I should have made this clear, somehow I thought "using conditions" implied it. Anyway, my original Idea was to keep the Condition in order to wake up the consumer only when he really has something to process. When you're using a simple Queue, you need to poll it constantly while a Condition simply wakes up! It might not make much difference to simply make the Thread sleep for some milliseconds and re-check the Queue, but it's still not as efficient as the Condition approach. However, I figured something an hour before, could you please review my edited question?

Comment: @NiklasR "When you're using a simple Queue, you need to poll it constantly while a Condition simply wakes up!" huh? No you don't. `Queue.get()` is blocking.

Comment: like millimoose said, `Queue.get()` is blocking. `Queue` is *perfect* for your use case. It was written exactly for that.

Comment: @millimoose Ahh thanks, I didn't know that! Now I remember though, that I tried to use the `Queue` class, but I also needed to iterate over the elements which is not supported by the `Queue.Queue` class.

Comment: @NiklasR There's also `collections.deque()` which supports bounding and nonlocking modification. (Not sure how you'd implement blocking gets with it.) Honestly, in your case, I'd consider figuring out a way to get around iterating over the Queue contents - it really doesn't make too much sense given the use case it's optimized for. (I.e. getting data from point A to point B in a threadsafe way.)